# Symfony2 and subdomains

Tags: apache, symfony, mod-rewrite, subdomain, virtualhost

On my computer, I have a Symfony2 project where routes are like that : **localhost/project/web/app.php/wiki/XXXXX**

I've got a domain and a subdomain and on my server, and I would like routes look like : **wiki.domain.com/XXXXX**

Actually, when I go to **wiki.domain.com**, I'm on the app.php page because I redirected the subdomain to project/web/app.php thanks to this vhost :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName wiki.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/project/web/
        <Directory /var/www/project/web>
                DirectoryIndex app.php
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]
    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]
    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

But if I want to go to the route XXXXX I always have to go to **wiki.domain.com/app.php/wiki/XXXXX**

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: app.php is displayed in `dev` environment.. you can get rid of that in `prod`

Comment: `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug` use this

Comment: I tried the command but it doesn't change. I checked in app.php if the line `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);` had the value "prod" and it's good.

Comment: after this your subdomain will be `wiki.domain.com/wiki/XXXXX` because you have wiki in your route at localhost

Comment: After the command, my subdomain is still `wiki.domain.com/app.php/wiki/XXXXX` and `wiki.domain.com/wiki/XXXXX` doesn't work, I've got a 404.

Comment: Remove DirectoryIndex app.PHP line

Comment: have a look at [THIS](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html)